# named scope works but association not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Made a named scope:

```
class Activity
  scope :active, where("active = ?", true)

  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

`a = Activity.active` work fine but the association `a.attachments` not (NoMethodError: undefined method `attachments')

Comment: Why did you expect when calling attachment on a scope (ie on a collection of activities)

Answer (score 0):

When you reference a scope like that, you get back an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, not a model instance, that's why Rails complains there's no association method. You can either do something like this, for example

```
a.first.attachments
```

or

```
att = a.includes(:attachments)
```

and then access attachments belonging to an activity within this collection

```
att[0].attachments
```

Comment: Hi, it does not work for me. this is my code

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :city
        has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable 
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments

 scope :homepage_city, where("homepage_city = ?", true)
end


class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
 
 belongs_to :city


   scope :homepage_city, where("homepage_city = ?", true)

 has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable 
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end

Comment: Hi, it does not work for me. this is my code

class Thing
        belongs_to :city
        has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable 
 scope :homepage_city, where("homepage_city = ?", true)

class Activity 
 belongs_to :city
   scope :homepage_city, where("homepage_city = ?", true)
 has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable 
   

Controller 
@deals = Activity.homepage_city + Thing.homepage_city
@att = @deals.includes(:attachments)

View
- @deals.each do |a|
= image_tag(a.file.url)
                  
I get error "undefined method `includes'" What am i doing wrong?
Ciao..remco

Comment: This statement: `@deals = Activity.homepage_city + Thing.homepage_city` converts `@deals` to `Array` (because of the +), so you can't chain conditions on it any longer. You'll have to either do two separate queries on `Thing` and `Activity` models, or use STI and query on the parent model (but I'm not sure it's appropriate in your case).